# Selective file read in Ruby

Tags: ruby, seek

I have a huge file that looks like this:

```
7

bla1
blala
blabla
blab
blals
blable
bla

more here..
```

The first numbers tells how many values I will have. The thing, is that i just want to point directly to the line 11 (text "more here.."), without having to read all those values before. In my case, I have a big amount of numbers, so it has to be optimized.

Would you recommend me something?

Comment: Have you considered importing it into an SQLite database (or a key-value database like GDBM)? Then you'd just have to do the ugly full scan once. Text files and random access aren't friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make something file-like that will skip past the first N lines:

```
SkipFile.open("/tmp/frarees") do |ln|
  puts ln                                   # "more here.." and so on
end

puts SkipFile.new("/tmp/frarees").readline  # "more here.."
```

Like so:

```
class SkipFile
  def self.open(fn, &block)
    sf = SkipFile.new(fn)
    return sf unless block
    sf.each(&block)
  end

  def initialize(fn)
    @f = File.open(fn)
    skip = @f.readline.to_i     # Skip N lines as prescribed by the file
    skip.times { @f.readline }  # this could be done lazily
  end

  def each(&block)
    @f.each(&block)
  end

  def readline
    @f.readline
  end
end
```

Easy to do if you just want to iterate forward through lines of a file.  It becomes arduous, however, if you want to mimic the `File` or `IO` interface exactly (but see [`Delegate`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/index.html)) and especially if you want to support rewindability back to the fake start of your file.

Answer (score 5):

You could probably use [File#seek](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M000931) to randomly access the file.

The problem with that approach is that it will just access data at a specified byte offset - not a line offset. If your file could give the byte offset at the start of the file to where the list finishes, then you could use that.

Comment: Yes I know, the thing is that I can't calc the byte offset (different line size), and I'm given the number of lines only :(

Answer (score 2):

Here's an elegant way to do it, probably not very efficient though as it requires loading the whole file into memory at once.

```
File.readlines(file_path)[10..-1] # indexing starts from 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to get any more efficient than this, since you'll have read the bytes in the file to figure out what is a "line".

```
f = File.open('./data')
(f.readline.to_i + 2).times { f.readline }
p f.readline
```